# Numerical range iterators in boost?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, iterator, range

I'm aware of the range iterators in boost, and as for [this reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/range/doc/boost_range.html), it seems there should be an easy way of doing what I want, but it's not obvious to me.

Say I want to represent a numerical range, 0 to 100 (inclusive or not), say `range(0,100)`. I would like to do something like:

```
for_each(range<int>(0,100).begin(), range<int>(0,100).end(), do_something);
```

where `do_something` is a functor. This iterators shouldn't have the overhead of having an underneath vector or something like this, but to just offer a sequence of integers. Is this possible with the range implementation in boost? Possible at all with normal, standard STL iterators?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[boost::counting_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html)

```
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

std::for_each( boost::counting_iterator<int>(0),
               boost::counting_iterator<int>(100),
               do_something );
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted... Don't know how I missed it searching through the boost libraries... :)

Comment: boost::for_each(boost::counting_range(0,100), std::cout << boost::lambda::_1);

Answer (score 11):

Just to add to the other answers if you're coming from a C++11 perspective - if you'd rather use modern for-each loops, you can do this even more cleanly with [boost counting_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html):

```
#include <boost/range/counting_range.hpp>

for(auto const &i : boost::counting_range(0, 10)) {
  std::cout << i;
}
```

Outputs:

> 0123456789

Comment: Excellent.  :) Thumbs up from me. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. It just seems boost::range doesn't have support for it out of the box, but you can

- use [`boost::counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html), which does just what you want
- implement a number-like object whose `operator*()` would return a number, and use that as an iterator for `range`