# Literal for ranges in C++11

Tags: c++11, for-loop, for-range

If I have this:

```
for (auto iSong = 1; iSong <= iMaxSongNumber; iSong++)
```

Can I use the new `for range` approach?

I understand that for containers they need a `begin` and `end` method for them to work. But if we have literal max values?

Comment: Ranges are not native to C++11, but there are libraries that can create them (and which can be used for e.g. ranged `for` loops).

Comment: Maybe try including <texas.h> ;)

Comment: @KubaWyrostek what is **texas.h**?

Comment: Sorry for that, it was not so clever joke about expecting "rangers" in c++.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek ROTFL

Comment: You need something like [`counting_range`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28099607/752976), but that's not in the standard. Use Boost or write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in mechanism to do this: range-based `for` works on something for which `begin` and `end` can be called.

I wrote a blog post about how to do this: https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/generating_sequences.html

Basically, you need to create a "virtual container" with iterators that update the count.

Comment: Thanks for the information you have provided. I don't think it is worth the effort for my needs. If there was something out of the box ... Also, in my instances I also need 1 stated indexing as opposed to 0 based. But thank you anyway. I will accept this answer.

Comment: The final code linked to from the blog post allows 1-based indexing. https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/files/numeric_range.cpp